# How do I install plupload through npm?

Tags: npm, plupload, package.json

I see plupload has a package.json file on their [Git](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload), but I can't find it on npm when I `npm view Plupload versions`. Is it possible to install this library through npm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is possible to specify a git remote url as the argument to `npm install`. So, in your case, you can use `npm install https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload` or even `npm install github:moxiecode/plupload`. You can read more about the supported arguments in the [documentation for npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

However, I do not believe this library was made to be installed through npm or `require`'d. It does not have a `main` file in its `package.json`, nor does `src/plupload.js` file export anything. If you need it in your project, it might be easier to just point your `<script>` to the appropriate url(s) in this [list](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/plupload).

Comment: what is the purpose of having a package.json file it it's not made to be installed through npm?

Comment: Probably so that they can define development dependencies like `jshint`, `jake`, and `uglify-js`.